# Upon login, session crashes and returns me to greeter

Tags: xorg, session

I'm running Elementary Luna Beta 1 and I'm running into some pretty difficult problems. Whenever I try logging in with the greeter (either pantheon-greeter or even lightdm-gtk-greeter), it immediately returns me to the login screen after the screen goes black.

I'm not seeing anything significant in `~/.xsession-errors` or in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Where else should I look for potential problems? How can I debug what's going wrong with my session? If I log into a guest session, everything works fine, but I can't log into my own account.

Comment: In this situation, the 1st thing to try is to create a new account and see if that crash the wm login also.

Comment: Ok, created new user with `useradd -m -s tester` and set password with `passwd tester` and was able to log in without any problems. No crashes, I am able to get into the session just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, I had some NVIDIA configuration in my home folder as well as `.Xauthority` files. I moved those into a backup folder and I was able to get in. As suggested elsewhere online, I then double-checked all of my power connections inside of my computer case, as this is often why drive issues happen.

Answer (score 1):

Base on feed back from comment and with minimum info in .xsession-errors. Do following

1. Check /var/log/syslog
2. Compare groups

   ```
   groups <username>
   ```
3. Compare home directory permission

   ```
   ls -lh /home
   ls -lh /home/<username>
   ```
4. Create new home directory and move stuff back one by one

   ```
   cd /home
   mv username username.old
   mkdir username
   chown username:username username
   ```

   Then try login from WM again. If that works, it is most likely some thing in those hidden directory stopping you from login, move those hidden directory from /home/username.old to /home/username one by one to pin point it.